# How to convert a long format Date to Human Readable format

Tags: python

I have a time stamp in the format `20140110143000` I need to convert it into a human readble format.

I am using the following code:

```
time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', time.localtime(20140110143000))
```

But it is giving the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#6>", line 1, in <module>
    time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', time.localtime(20140110143000))
ValueError: (22, 'Invalid argument')
```

Can any body please help me out?

Comment: The time.localtime expects seconds. just run this command help(time.localtime) for more clarity. use datetime instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

coincidentally `datetime` objects prints timestamp in `%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S` format. So, for printing `20140110143000` in required format you can simply convert it to a datetime object and print it

```
from datetime import datetime
print datetime.strptime("20140110143000", "%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
```

**output**

```
2014-01-10 14:30:00
```

Comment: Could you explain a bit *why* your code works? @Anand, if this helps you out, feel free to check this as the accepted answer!

Comment: My previous was not working probably because I used 'strftime' function. I have accepted your answer.

Comment: What if I have the timestamp in this format `20140110143000.7`?

When I follow the way, it gives error